# How to straighten edges along an axis point

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh, which on the bottom side, the edges are skewed. I 'm trying to figure how to align them on the X axis so they straighten up. my first thought was using the loop tools but they just distort my mesh.
So what's the correct method for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hoping this is the situation:

[image]

.. you have a good reference top edge to the plane containing the skew loops.

1. Create a Custom Orientation from the top edge by using the little '+' in the *Header > Transform Orientation* dropdown, and set Pivot to *Active Element*, then:

[image]

2. (above) Bottom edge selected, with its good reference vertex active,
   in the new orientation,
   <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> make the bottom edge parallel to the top edge.

[image]

3. Left edge, all verts selected, *Loop Tools > Space* make them regular

[image]

4. Same for the right edge.

If you're missing the good reference points in this answer, let us know what else you need to fix before following these steps.

Comment: Hi Robin. This method works well, but I believe I have misunderstood your method. I can align each line on the new axis perfectly but I have to each time move the cursor to the new vertices then select cursor to active then perform the S Shift Y 0, I tried to select all the lines and do your method but they all collapse into once vertex point.

Comment: https://ibb.co/7vvwPf6

Comment: Step 2, the scale to 0, applies _only to the bottom edge_. The subsequent steps assume you want evenly spaced loops, and use Loop Tools to space the loops evenly between the top (and now good) bottom edge, working  one side at a time. Did you want parallel, but unevenly spaced loops? If so, what would you want to use, to define the locations of the unevenly spaced loops?